# How to Binding ComboBox with TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a class named `Order` with properties of `ID` and `Name`.

I have an `ObservableCollection<Order>` named `AllOrder`.

I have a `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox Name="CID" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainScreen}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllOrder}" DisplayMemberPath="ID"/>
```

When I select the `ComboBox` I want `TextBox` to display `Name`, something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=CID,Path=SelectedItem,Display=Name}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to nested properties:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=CID, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
```

`SelectedItem` returns the currently selected `Order` object and `.Name` returns the value of the `Name` property of this one.

Comment: Well youresolution work fine but when i'm use it inside `DataGrid`, `TextBox` dosen't show up Name.

Comment: You should post the code of your attempt. Especially for beginners there is a lot you can do wrong, using WPF (I know, a'm a beginner as well).